# how can I fix the glitch in my jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im using this jquery code to switch page content on my site. It switches the content but it seems to flicker the page before switching to the new. I thought it might be to do with the CSS not loading through properly before it changes the content because my jquery scrollbar doesn't load properly if i've clicked the link to view the page however if I refresh the page just once it seems to be working fine again.

Is there someway the code can check everything is ready before switching to avoid the glitchy flickering?

here my code for switching the page content

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('#nav li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
        $('#content').load(toLoad)
       }                                            
});

$('#nav li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').fadeOut('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').fadeIn('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;

});

 });
```

Comment: Can we have a link to the page that "flickers"? Why do you set `var href = $('#nav li a').each();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see one issue, these two lines:

```
$('#content').load(toLoad,showNewContent())
$('#content').fadeIn('normal',hideLoader());
```

need to be:

```
$('#content').load(toLoad,showNewContent);
$('#content').fadeIn('normal',hideLoader);
```

If you aren't passing any data, you can omit it, and the complete argument needs to be reference to a named function or an anonymous function. what you had was the result of executing `showNewContent()` which is undefined.

```
function showNewContent() {
  $("body").scrollTop();
  $('#content').fadeIn('normal',hideLoader);  
}
```

Comment: thank you mate, that seems to have worked perfectly! However my scroll bar still seems to glitch, I need to refresh the browser for it to start working properly if I click to its page from the navigation link. could that be something to do with this content changer jquery or the scroll bar's jquery?

Comment: I think you are running into a situation where the height of the page changes to smaller than the old content, therefore the viewport gets shifted up. I suggest adding a scrollTo call in the showNewContent method to always scroll the browser to the top when new content is shown.

Comment: like this? function showNewContent() $('#content').scrollTo.fadeIn('normal',hideLoader);